# sharing users table across multiple database for single Login

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, drupal-7

In my Drupal 7 installation I have:

1. Main site: example.com
2. Sub Domains: blog.example.com, forum.example.com (all in same domain)

I have database design in such a way:

- Main Site uses: main_db
- Sub Domain uses: blog_db, forum_db (all separate databases)

When the user register's in main site, they should also able to use other sub-domains without registering again and again. I can copy/sync the users table from main_db to other dbs, but that not suitable solution. as it creates 3 instances of same data.

Is there any solution to store users table in main_db and access it via other dbs ? The proper term would be, how to share the users table from main database to other databases.

Comment: http://mah.moud.info/drupal-7-multisite-basic-guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query from other databases in MySQL. Simply prefix the database in front of the table name.

This is from [documentation of the SELECT statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

> You can refer to a table within the default database as tbl_name, or
>   as db_name.tbl_name to specify a database explicitly.

Just make sure you edit the permissions so that your user can access the required databases.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Just a question, do you think it'll slow my database while fetching the result from multiple databases ?

Comment: According to this previous answer, there is no performance penalty for querying across databases: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224136/performance-of-querying-across-two-mysql-databases-on-the-same-server